# magento2.4 how to upload Pdf file to gallery and insert them to cms page

Tags: cms-pages, magento2.4.4, gallery, magento2-cloud, pdf-uploads

I have to upload PDF files from admin gallery and insert them to CMS-page, I can see extensions available for product attributes PDF upload but I need to use them an CMS-page through gallery. Kindly advice how to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Please create the following module:

**app/code/Vendor/WysiwygDownloads/registration.php:**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_WysiwygDownloads',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app/code/Vendor/WysiwygDownloads/etc/module.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_WysiwygDownloads" />
</config>
```

**app/code/Vendor/WysiwygDownloads/etc/adminhtml/di.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Images\Storage">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="img_storage_custom_plugin" sortOrder="10" type="Vendor\WysiwygDownloads\Plugin\Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Images\Storage"/>
        <arguments>
            <argument name="extensions" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="allowed" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="pdf" xsi:type="string">application/pdf</item>
                </item>
                <item name="image_allowed" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="pdf" xsi:type="string">application/pdf</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2" type="Vendor\WysiwygDownloads\Image\Adapter\Gd2" />
</config>
```

**app/code/Vendor/WysiwygDownloads/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php:**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\WysiwygDownloads\Image\Adapter;

use Magento\Framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2 as OriginalGd2;
use Exception;
use OverflowException;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Vendor\WysiwygDownloads\Plugin\Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Images\Storage;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException;

class Gd2 extends OriginalGd2
{
    public function __construct(
        Filesystem $filesystem,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($filesystem, $logger, $data);
    }


    /**
     * Open image for processing
     *
     * @param string $filename
     * @return void
     * @throws OverflowException|FileSystemException
     */
    public function open($filename)
    {
        $pathInfo = pathinfo($filename);
        if (!key_exists('extension', $pathInfo) || !in_array($pathInfo['extension'], Storage::FILE_TYPES)) {
            parent::open($filename);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Save image to specific path.
     * If some folders of path does not exist they will be created
     *
     * @param null|string $destination
     * @param null|string $newName
     * @return void
     * @throws Exception  If destination path is not writable
     */
    public function save($destination = null, $newName = null)
    {
        $fileName = $this->_prepareDestination($destination, $newName);
        $pathInfo = pathinfo($fileName);
        if (!key_exists('extension', $pathInfo) || !in_array($pathInfo['extension'], Storage::FILE_TYPES)) {
            parent::save($destination, $newName);
        }
    }
}
```

**app/code/Vendor/WysiwygDownloads/Plugin/Magento/Cms/Model/Wysiwyg/Images/Storage.php:**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\WysiwygDownloads\Plugin\Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Images;

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Module\Dir\Reader;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Images\Storage as OriginalStorage;
use Magento\Framework\Module\Dir;

class Storage {

    const FILE_TYPES = ['pdf'];

    protected $type;
    /**
     * @var Reader
     */
    private Reader $moduleReader;
    /**
     * @var Filesystem
     */
    private Filesystem $filesystem;

    /**
     * Storage constructor.
     *
     * @param Reader $moduleReader
     * @param Filesystem $filesystem
     */
    public function __construct(
        Reader $moduleReader,
        Filesystem $filesystem
    ){
        $this->moduleReader = $moduleReader;
        $this->filesystem = $filesystem;
    }

    /**
     * @param OriginalStorage $subject
     * @param $type
     * @return void
     */
    public function beforeGetAllowedExtensions(OriginalStorage $subject, $type)
    {
        $this->type = $type;
    }


    /**
     * @param OriginalStorage $subject
     * @param $result
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterGetAllowedExtensions(OriginalStorage $subject, $result)
    {
        $fileTypes = self::FILE_TYPES;
        return array_merge($result, $fileTypes);
    }

    /**
     * @param OriginalStorage $subject
     * @param $source
     * @param $keepRatio
     * @return array
     */
    public function beforeResizeFile(OriginalStorage $subject, $source, $keepRatio = true)
    {
        $sourceInfo = explode('.', $source);
        $fileExtension = end($sourceInfo);
        if (strtolower($fileExtension) === 'pdf') {
            $mediaPath = $this->filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath() . 'pdf-icon.png';
            if (!file_exists($mediaPath)) {
                copy(
                    $this->moduleReader->getModuleDir(
                        Dir::MODULE_VIEW_DIR,
                        'Vendor_WysiwygDownloads'
                    ) . '/adminhtml/web/images/pdf-icon.png',
                    $mediaPath
                );
            }
            $source = $mediaPath;
        }
        return [$source, $keepRatio];
    }
}
```

and of course the image:
**app/code/Vendor/WysiwygDownloads/view/adminhtml/web/images**
Upload this image:

[image]

You can add more file types in the `FILE_TYPES` const (**gif, xml, zip** etc), but you will need to update also the di.xml file.
This is a simplified version of this module: https://github.com/experius/Magento-2-Module-Experius-WysiwygDownloads. Credit goes to them!
Also the simplified version is running just fine on Magento 2.4.6 .

**How to use ?**
[image]

Good luck !